# Remote jar not found in build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle

In my application (MyApp), I am using an another project(Appox) as library and in this (Appox) project, I want to include bugsense-jar from their repository. Now in build.gradle of Appox, I am including it in this way

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
   maven { url 'http://www.bugsense.com/gradle/' }
}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
   compile 'com.bugsense.trace:bugsense:3.6'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
           //....
        }
    }
}
```

But on compiling I am always getting the error `Failed to find com.bugsense.trace:bugsense:3.6`
Am I including it in the correct way? Is it possible that the file is not even present in their repo?

Answer (score 4):

Just to bring this up to date, Bugsense has been renamed Mint, so the references to the bugsense.com repo are broken. So, update your Gradle file with the following:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    maven { url "https://mint.splunk.com/gradle/" }
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.splunk.mint:mint:4.3.0"
}
```

From: http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/MintAndroidSDK/latest/DevGuide/Requirementsandinstallation

If you're updating old code, you'll also need to update your imports and rename any instances of `BugSenseHandler` in your code to `Mint`. (http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/MintAndroidSDK/latest/DevGuide/AddSplunkMINTtoyourproject)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://www.bugsense.com/gradle/' }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    compile 'com.bugsense.trace:bugsense:3.6'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
           ....
        }
    }
}
```

Changes made :

1. All Maven repositories declared at the same time
2. `mavenCentral()` is declared in the last position

Sources :

http://blog.bugsense.com/post/58900337206/gradle-repository-is-now-available-for-bugsense
http://gradleproject.wordpress.com/2013/02/14/multiple-maven-repositories-in-gradle/